# Library for client using socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I'm new to node.js, so my question might be totally idiotic, but here we go:

I've read many articles about how to use socket.io, and to build the server is quite straightforward, but when it comes the client, it always start with:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

and I have no idea where is this file coming from.

Can someone please explain me what I'm missing?

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>WE DO Chat</h1>

        <script src="http://localhost:1180/nodetest/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
var io = require('socket.io').listen(1180);

io.sockets.on('message', function (message, callback) {
    socket.broadcast.emit(message);
});

io.sockets.on('connect', function (socket) {
    console.log("Client connected");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the socket.io client is part of the socket.io library (available on socket.io & github).  The client library is used to spawn the connection to the server side implementation of socket.io

socket.io.js is served by the Node.js server.

```
<script src="http://nodejs.address:port/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Comment: Im working on localhost (http://localhost/nodetest/) and its not working with: <script src="http://localhost/nodetest/socket.io/socket.io.js">

Comment: just wondering - have you tried specifying the exact location of the socket.io client library in your html page?

Comment: alos, please share your js file used as you main node.js file

Comment: I didnt get that the server was the one delivering the file for the client. I changed it using the server port, and it worked. But I still get a message error:  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier (socket.io.js:1)

Comment: Try hitting the socket.io.js file directly in your browser to see what's up

Comment: I get a "Welcome to socket.io." message. I edited the original post with the files.

Answer (score 1):

When utilizing the server-side (node.js npm) socket.io library this js resource is automatically matched against and delivered for the the given resource path. Try if your integration works correctly by just calling it with curl e.g.:

```
curl http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js
```

Comment: curl: (7) couldn't connect to host

Comment: So how do I find out the port?

Comment: You said _build the server is quite straight forward_ - so you _must_ already have some kind of node.js server running on your system. Did you ever execute something like `node app.js` or `node server.js` on the command line?

Comment: I see! so the file for the client is delivered through the server, using the same port where it's listening! :) I changed it and it worked but now I get this error on the console: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier (socket.io.js:1)

Comment: In your edit your code shows `<script src="http://localhost:1180/nodetest/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`. But it _must_ read something like `<script src="http://localhost:1180/socket.io/socket.io.js">` or just `<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js">`. Or did you copy some resource called socket.io.js to a directory `/nodetest` in a public folder that serves static content? I'm not sure if you really got the point @ali haider and me where trying to point out.